# Show $P(\sigma\tau)=P(\sigma)P(\tau)$

Tags: calculus, matrices, summation, matrix-calculus

$\forall\sigma,\tau\in S_n$, $P(\sigma\tau)=P(\sigma)P(\tau)$

Definition: To each $\sigma\in S_n$ we may associate an $n\times n$ permutation matrix $P(\sigma)$ given by

$P_{ij}(\sigma)=\delta_{i,\sigma(j)}$

Proof:

$$[P(\sigma)P(\tau)]_{ik}=\sum_{j=1}^nP_{ij}(\sigma)P_{jk}(\tau)=\sum_{j=1}^n\delta_{i,\sigma(j)}\delta_{j,\tau(k)}=\delta_{i,\sigma(\tau(k))}=P_{ik}(\sigma\tau)$$

I dont undetstand the step:

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\delta_{i,\sigma(j)}\delta_{j,\tau(k)}=\delta_{i,\sigma(\tau(k))}$$

By the summation convention we can ignore the summation sign,

How does $$\delta_{i,\sigma(j)}\delta_{j,\tau(k)}=\delta_{i,\sigma(\tau(k))}$$

Comment: What is the defitinion of Kronecker delta function?

Comment: I thought it was the kronecker delta function

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\delta_{i,\sigma(j)}\delta_{j,\tau(k)}=1\iff  i=\sigma(j),j=\tau(k)\iff i=\sigma(\tau(k))\iff\delta_{i,\sigma(\tau(k))}=1$$

Comment: Great thanks, was trying to use that relation but couldn't work out how.

Comment: @Dansmith you're welcome.